# How to display a object inside an array in a ejs file

Tags: mongodb, schema, ejs

I am trying to display a array inside a object in EJS but I cant get it to work.  For this I am using a mongodb schema and then I am viewing the schema inside a EJS file.

This is in the schema User:

```js
 shoppingcart: [{
  productname: Array,
  productimage : Array,
  productprice: Array,
  Productamount: Array
  }]
```

I have tried things like:

```html
<%= user.shoppingcart.productname%>

<%= user.shoppingcart.["productname"][0]%>

<%= user.shoppingcart.productname[0]%>
```

But none of these work, so my question is how do you display this in a EJS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I have found the solution, turned out that I messed it up in the schema. The array field shoppingcart with objects inside, turned out to be inside another object. Which is why ejs couldn't find the shoppingcart array.

The solution is: <%=user.shoppingcart[0].productname%>